# My laptops automatically lose an ip address on my home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a home network with:

- Modem + wifi router - Cisco DPC3825 - (1) - SSID 7a567d
- WIFI extender. - [Almond Securifi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087NZ31S) (2) - SSID 7a567d_almond
- Both the above are on channel 9
- MAC Filtering is disabled on (1)
- There is nothing in IP Address filtering on (1).

I have 6 devices on the network. Some connected to (1) and some connected to (2). At times I have notices that the device will stay connected but lose the ipaddress it had. So I get an error like "No Internet connection". The problem goes away when I reconnect the extender (2) to the cisco router (1).

I'm looking for ways to resolve this.

What are my options and if I need to change some settings, which should I change?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the problem might have to do with you running 2 DHCP servers - if this is the case you will definately want to disable one of them, presumably the one on the range extender.

Comment: weird. The device I am using as range extender (http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087NZ31S) has a "range-extender" mode which suggests that the DHCP server shouldn't be running.

Comment: From the user manual: `Note: If you want your Almond to issue IP addresses, i.e. to act as a DHCP server, then choose the Wireless WAN option instead of Range Extender 
option. In Range Extender mode, the Almond relies on your main router to act as the DHCP server.`http://www.firmware.securifi.com/AL1/AlmondQuickGuide.pdf